# Maven: Change property for "mvn test" command

Tags: maven, testing, skip

I couldn't find answer to this question on the Internet, so I'm asking here.
I would like to skip certain plugins execution on a property value:

```xml
<properties>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
</properties>
...

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>1</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skip>${skipTests}</skip>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        ...
```

And my goal is to have property ${skipTests} to TRUE value when I call

```xml
mvn clean install
```

And it should be FALSE when I call

```xml
mvn test
```

I would like to not command below (which actually work, but is ugly):

```xml
mvn test -DskipTests=false
```

How should it be done?

Comment: First it looks a little bit strange to use skipTests for exec-maven-plugin ? You know maven-surefire-plugin ? What kind of tests are you running. Furthermore there is no real difference between `mvn install` and `mvn test` cause the life cycle phase *test* is before *install*. So the wish you have can't be fulfilled in that way. It might be better to use a profile to have things like `mvn -Ptest install` but i don't recommend that.

Comment: I would like to turn off tests while mvn clean install and run them only when I call mvn test

Comment: You've written the same as in your question but didn't give supplemental information. May be you can give more information why/what you like to achieve otherwise we don't get a step forward.

Comment: I'm testing many data on database which is not available at all PC's used in company. I would like to know if there is any mechanism to have different properties for `mvn test` and for `mvn clean install`

Comment: So now this is an integration test and *not* unit testing which means the best solution in Maven is to use a separate module which can be controled by a profile, but not the way you like to do. Furthermore if you use them as integration tests they will run only if you do `mvn install` or may be better `mvn verify` whereas via `mvn test` only unit tests will run.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and involvement I will read more